# Firefox does not listen to my settings

Tags: firefox, settings

In firefox, the first time it boots it always tries to reopen previous tabs (and fails), even though I've set for it to open things in new tabs. It seems any secondary windows open in the homepage (as it should).

Any idea where I should look?

Comment: Please create a separate 2nd question for the 2nd question. AU is set up to work like that ;)

Comment: Sorry, thought they might be related (something to do with Ubuntu and settings in general) so I put them together

Comment: There is a settings file inside your home (~./mozilla/). The setting you are trying to change should be stored there ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Edit -> Preferences` menu on the 1st tab `General`, the 1st setting (Start Options) is to define what Firefox will do when starting. You have 3 options there:

- Open Homepage
- Open Blank Page
- Restore Windows and tabs from previous session

If you set it to the 1st one, it will only open your Homepage when starting and not try to restore previous tabs (if it had been closed properly before). If you logout or shutdown without closing Firefox, it will always (I think) restore the tabs that where open when you logged off.

Obs: not sure about the exact words of the menu because mine is not in English but the meaning should be the same.

Comment: It seems it was about trying to restore tabs if you don't manually close it. Thanks!